# Flatten a dictionary of objects

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this :

```
foo = {'a': [{'11': 'coucou'}, {'22': 'test'}], 'b': [{'33': 'plop'}, {'44': 'last'}]}
```

An I want to remove the first level to obtain this :

```
[{'11': 'coucou'}, {'22': 'test'}, {'33': 'plop'}, {'44': 'last'}]
```

I tried this without success :

```
bar = {k
       for d in foo.values()
       for k in d}
```

The error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

I understand that my second iteration failed but I don't now why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your example output is a list, and your comprehension is a set. Try

```
bar = [k
       for d in foo.values()
       for k in d]
```

to get a list.  You could also do

```
from itertools import chain

bar = list(chain.from_iterable(foo.values()))
```

Comment: Of course you are right, I'm not use to comprehension syntax.

Comment: `sum(foo.values(),[])`??

Comment: @Onyambu I think you'll find that to be surprisingly inefficient.  Because `alist + anotherlist` has to scan through both lists, I would expect that to be `O(n**2)`